# android sqlite cursor result with List NameValuePair

Tags: php, android, xml, sqlite

i build android 4.0  apps   with a cart handle a bunch of selection stored in data/data/.../cartlist.db and need to know how to related the cursor result with List NameValuePair, 
here is my activity

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.sendorder);


  postData();
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 



      String[] columns = new String[] { "_id","name",
              "qty", "price"  };

      Cursor messagesCursor= getContentResolver().query(
            MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null,
              null);    

        int theTotal = messagesCursor.getCount();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Total6: " + theTotal, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        int idCol = messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
        int nameCol = messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("name");
        int qtyCol = messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("qty");
        int priceCol = messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("price");

        while (messagesCursor.moveToNext()) {
            columns[0] = Integer.toString((messagesCursor.getInt(idCol)));
            quantity = messagesCursor.getString(nameCol);
            product = messagesCursor.getString(qtyCol);
            cost = messagesCursor.getString(priceCol);

        }   


            }    
 public void postData() {

        // Creating HTTP client
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Creating HTTP Post
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost( "http://example.com/droid/order.php");

        // Building post parameters
        // key and value pair
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty", quantity));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product",product));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price",cost));
        // Url Encoding the POST parameters
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // writing error to Log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Making HTTP Request
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            // writing response to log
            Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

Comment: you forgot the question

Comment: Yea...what's being asked here?

Comment: So, it is a `not constructive` question?

Comment: my question is about to take sqlite data who is store the selection (quantity name price)and send to my sqlserver i got 2 php  json  xml file ready and tested on my sqlserver

Comment: really sorry this is my first post

Answer (score 0):

i find out just misplace the name value pair and clean some curly bracket hope to the answer help some one

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.sendorder);

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 



  String[] columns = new String[] { "_id","name",
          "qty", "price"  };

  Cursor messagesCursor= getContentResolver().query(
        MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null,
          null);    

    int theTotal = messagesCursor.getCount();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Total6: " + theTotal, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    int idCol = messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
    int nameCol = messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("name");
    int qtyCol = messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("qty");
    int priceCol = messagesCursor.getColumnIndex("price");

    while (messagesCursor.moveToNext()) {
        columns[0] = Integer.toString((messagesCursor.getInt(idCol)));
        quantity = messagesCursor.getString(nameCol);
        product = messagesCursor.getString(qtyCol);
        cost = messagesCursor.getString(priceCol);
    // Building post parameters
    // key and value pair
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qty", quantity));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product",product));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price",cost));


    // Creating HTTP client
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Creating HTTP Post
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost( "http://example.com/droid/order.php");


    // Url Encoding the POST parameters
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // writing error to Log
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Making HTTP Request
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        // writing response to log
        Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // writing exception to log
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```